# Mistake: "pay attention for"

Tags: prepositions

I've heard this phrase recently:

- Are you paying attention ***for*** this crucial information?

It's a mistake, isn't it?

I wouldn't ask you about that, if this person wasn't a British one.

Why did she say so?

Comment: Yes, the standard expression is _pay attention to_ something. Even native speakers don't get their own language right all the time.

Comment: 'Be alert for' something would be better.

Comment: Because she mangled her words. It happens. :)

Answer (score 2):

In spoken English such a construct is possible.  If I tell someone to *Pay attention **for** the mail*, what I'm actually suggesting is that they *Pay attention for [the **arrival** of] the mail*.  The same understanding would apply to *crucial information*.

I would not suggest writing this way but people often shortcut their speaking in this manner.